# Navigation Controller behaviour for a subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I've used Navigation Controllers before to allow pushing/popping of views.  However, that was used in instances where I wanted the *entire* view pushed/popped.

I now have a situation like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|                                      |
| +---------------------------------+  |
| |                                 |  |
| |            Sub View             |  |
| |                                 |  |
| +---------------------------------+  |
|                                      |
|              Main View               |
|                                      |
+--------------------------------------+
```

I would like to have the Sub View governed by a Navigation Controller, such that I can push/pop views into it while keeping the Main View the same.

Is this possible?  If so, could you provide guidance on how would I set this up in my project?

Comment: does the sub view really need to be a subview or can it be an independent view as well? (I am thinking about making the UINavigationController transparent)

Comment: After watching the vid rob suggested below it all fell into place. Specifically this method from the new iOS 5 UIViewController API makes this a synch: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need your main view controller to be a container view controller.  There is some documentation for this in the UIViewController Class Reference, but I recommend watching the *Implementing UIViewController Containment* video from WWDC 2011.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

Comment: As long as you're targeting 5.0+, this is THE way to go.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look, I'm targeting 5.0.

Comment: That video was very enlightening. The new parent/child API for view controllers is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, it seems you can just use a subview and add it to the mainview. When done remove it from the mainview. Assuming you are in a UIViewController class, you can do the following:

```
UIView *subView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame: blah];
// subView settings

[self.view addSubView: subview];
[subView release]; subView = nil;
```

When you are all done you can simply remove the subView from the superView. You can also use the tag property of the subView to track specific subViews if the need may be.

Comment: This was something I had thought of as well.  I figured I'd hold out though until I knew for certain I couldn't use the nice Navigation Controller will all it's sweet animation effects and what-not.  Thanks for your answer.